# How to change the value of __EVENTTARGET from server side in Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Question is so simple,

i can change the value of **__EVENTTARGET** from client side using

```
document.forms.ParentForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = "";
```

But how to do this from server side.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: State the requirement

Comment: i just wan to know why is this minus vote for?

Answer (score 1):

You cant directly modify it, but you can do something like this in the Page_Load:

```
Server.Transfer(String.Format(Request.Path + "?__EVENTTARGET={0}", "some_control_id"), true);
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to do it in Page_Load. but i need somewhere else. @jannagy02

Comment: But if you use this, I recommend that add the __EVENTARGUMENT as well:

Server.Transfer(String.Format(Request.Path + "?__EVENTTARGET={0}&__EVENTARGUMENT={1}", "some_control_id", "event_arg"), true);

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] = "";
```

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.dll. Collection is read-only.